# Possible to pass parameters to a skin?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe, flex4

I have 2 skins, almost identical, but differ in 1 small way that can be accounted for if I could pass a Boolean to the skin while assigning it to the host component (a button).

```
<s:Button skinClass="MyBtnSkin" />
```

Is there a way while assigning the skin to the button, I could also pass a parameter to the skin somehow?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to create a Button subclass and add your custom boolean property in it.

```
<s:MyCustomButton skinClass"MyBtnSkin" customProperty="true" />
```

Updating your skin file when customProperty changes could be done with binding afterwards.

```
<Rect ... visible={hostComponent.customProperty}>
```

Comment: Doesn't he has to set that property as @bindable also?